# VB script to find current location?

Tags: vba, excel

I have bp.xlsm file in the folder C:\tf\ExcellLaunch

In bp.xlsm file, sheet1, I have a button. When I click the button, I should get the path C:\tf\ExcellLaunch.

I am using the following code:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strCurDir = WshShell.currentDirectory

MsgBox (strCurDir)
```

what I get here is c:\uers\MyName\Documents

problem - How to find the file path of bp.xlsm in vb script? 
Expected output is C:\tf\ExcellLaunch  ( not c:\uers\MyName\Documents)

Comment: What is the link between VBScript and the worksheet? If you mean *VBA* a workbook has a `Path` property, E.g. `ActiveWorkbook.Path`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code it will Give you the path of current location-

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

MyFullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName 

MsgBox (MyFullName)

End Sub
```

Regards
Nitin